# unir Qlabel en un Qdialog

Tags: c++, qt

Tengo una duda con respecto a como conectar un `QLabel` en un `QDialog`.

La idea es poder abrir un `QDialog` antes de ejecutar el programa.

Dejo parte del código:

```
QDialog jjj;
QLabel *logojjj;
    logojjj->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(QImage(":/icons/jjj_2015_2.jpg")).scaled(QSize(120,120),Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
jjj.show();
Gui::MainWindow win;
sleep(3);
jjj.close();
win.show();
return app.exec();
```

Ese `QLabel` quiero dejarlo dentro del `QDialog` (todo esto está dentro del main).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QLabel *logojjj;
logojjj->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(// ...
```

¿En qué punto estás creando el `QLabel`? En el código que muestras estás declarando un puntero y seguidamente usando un supuesto objeto apuntado por el mismo... pero no has inicializado el puntero en ningún sitio. Si no te has saltado líneas en el ejemplo esto provocará una caida del programa.

```
QLabel *logojjj = new QLabel(&jjj);
logojjj->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage( // ...
```

Con esto la etiqueta ya debería aparecer dentro de `jjj`.

Por cierto, plantéate la posibilidad de dejar el diálogo diseñado con el editor de formularios y así evitas lidiar con el código que diseña las ventanas... que puede ser caótico en extremo.

Comment: Probé agregando eso y solo modifico el tamaño del Qdialog, sin agregar el contenido del Qlabel al Qdialog